# Using file manager new directory not working

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code, but this code is not working is return me an error for permission.

```
   let fileManager = FileManager.default

    // Create 'subfolder' directory

    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: "subfolder", withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
    }

    let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!

    print("\(documentsUrl)")
```

** error **

> oops! Something went wrong: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513
>   "You don’t have permission to save the file “subfolder”."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should provide the full path of your new directory as like below.

```
let applicationDocumentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last!

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: applicationDocumentsDirectory + "/subfolder", withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: you have idea about different-different type collage frame in iOS ? @Natarajan

Comment: You are welcome!